# Change pixel color in android display

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel, framebuffer, surfaceflinger

I want to change pixel color via android application using background.
It means entire screen, not image file.

How can I modify pixel color?

Result of searching, I could find "Bitmap", "Surfaceflinger", "Framebuffer".

but, I don't know what is correct way.

Answer (score 0):

The concept `SurfaceFlinger` and `Framebuffer` is a low level concept in Android system. In application level, which built on framework, these concepts are opaque.

As `Bitmap`, it's not very necessary if you just change the background color.

You can just simply do like following in your `Activity`.

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.color_res_id);
// or change the root view background
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_res_id);
```

If you are novice in Android app development, you can start reading the training [here](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html), it's a good source for beginner to start.